# how to opacity the asp.net page on button click , till procees get complete

Tags: asp.net, opacity, buttonclick

how to opacity the asp.net page on button click , till procees get complete of respective button.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a regular postback, use client side javascript to disable the button before the actual postback happens.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="myBtn" OnClick="YourServerSidePostBack" 
     OnClientClick="document.getElementById('<%= myBtn.ClientID %>').disabled = true;" />
```